# Concatenate rows into one and count the row based on id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

**post_table**

```
id_post | post_text                      
1       | great view                    
2       | happy breakfast           
3       | good night everybody
```

**comment_table**

```
id_comment | comment_text         | id_post      
1          | that's amazing       | 1         
2          | of course, the best  | 1       
3          | wish me there        | 1     
4          | yes, happy breakfast | 2    
5          | hehe                 | 2
```

**attach_picture**

```
id_picture | picture_name | id_post  
1          | pict_1       | 1  
2          | pict_2       | 1
```

I want to make a query that can make view like this:

```
id_post | post_text           | picture_name   | comment_count  
1       | great view          | pict_1, pict_2 | 3  
2       | happy breakfast     | null           | 2  
3       | goodnight everybody | null           | 0
```

I write query like this:

```
select a.id_post, a.post_text, b.picture_name, count(c.id_comment) as comment_count
from post_table left join
     attach_picture
     on a.id_post=b.id_post left join
     comment_table c
     on a.id_post=c.id_post
group by a.id_post
```

The result of the query is:

```
id_post | post_text           | picture_name  | comment_count  
1       | great view          | pict_1        | 6  
2       | happy breakfast     | null          | 2  
3       | goodnight everybody | null          | 0
```

The result is `picture_name` just catch 1 `picture_name` even the `id_post` have more than 1 `picture_name`, and the `comment_count` shows amount of `picture_name` * `comment_count`.

Please can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your query readily to do what you want:

```
select pt.id_post, pt.post_text,
       group_concat(distinct ap.picture_name) as picture_names,
       count(distinct c.id_comment) as comment_count
from post_table pt left join
     attach_picture ap
     on pt.id_post = ap.id_post left join
     comment_table c
     on pt.id_post = c.id_post
group by pt.id_post;
```

This query is doing more work than it needs, because you are joining the posts along two different dimensions.  Hence, for each post, you are getting a Cartesian product for all comments and images.  If you have only a few comments and posts for a given user, then this approach is fine.  If you had thousands of each, then this could get rather inefficient.  In that case, the solution is to aggregate before doing the joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id_post, a.post_text, GROUP_CONCAT(b.picture_name),  (select count(id) from comment_table where id_post = a.id)  as comment_count
from post_table a
left join attach_picture on a.id_post=b.id_post 
left join comment_table c on a.id_post=c.id_post
group by a.id_post
```